# Inputting a Key during a Loop in Java applet for animation purposes

Tags: java, applet, awt, paint, keylistener

I'm learning how to make an Applet using Java in the form of a game. In the game, I have a character sprite drawn at the center and moves when the player presses w a s d.

It goes like this:

```
public game extends applet implements KeyListener {
    int x, y;
    URL url;
    Image image;
    public void init() {
        x = getSize().width/2;
        y = getSize().height/2;
        url = new URL(getCodeBase());
        image = getImage(url, "player.gif"); //take note that this is a still image
        addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, x, y, 32, 32, this); //the size of the image is 32x32
    }
    public void KeyPressed(arg0) {
    char c = arg0.getKeyChar();
    switch(c) {
        case 'w':  
            y -= 10;
            break; 
        /*And so on. You guys know how it works.*/      
    }
    repaint();
}
```

My problem is, the character sprite seems dull when the user doesn't press anything. What I want to do is to make the Image an array of images and put a simple image animation by looping the array in paint like so:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for(int i = 0; ; i++) {
        g.drawImage(image[i], x, y, 32, 32, this);
        if(i == image.size() - 1) { i = 0;}
    }
}
```

However, if I do this, I won't be able to get anymore KeyEvents that would activate when the user wants to move. My question is this: How will I make it so that my character does an animation when the program is "idle" (i.e. the user isn't pressing anything) while still maintaining the capability to take in KeyEvents (e.g. moving when the player types in w, a, s, or d, and then continuing the idle animation after repainting)?

Thanks in advance.

PS. I'm still quite a beginner in Java so sorry if my code is not very nice. Any advice is welcome.

Comment: 1.  Any advice is welcome --->  [Oracle tutorial - 2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html), 2. use [Swing instead of AWT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html), 3. don't use KeyListener, [use KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), 4. [short_cut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+paintcomponent?sort=newest&pageSize=15)

Comment: 5. Don't try and perform animation within the `paint` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your application multithreaded so that the painting runs in a separate thread.

Otherwise you will have the painting blocked while waiting for the next key.

This is not a trivial change to your code though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you would give yourself a new class, say *InterestingCharacter*, which can cycle through any of N states (corresponding to your N images). You clearly can't let any paint method run infinitely, but if your *InterestingCharacter* could render itself in its current state you might be onto something with that. Maybe it will be enough that this *InterestingCharacter* knows what state it is in and then some other object manages the rendering. Would it be helpful if the *InterestingCharacter* could tell you that its state has changed and so needs to be rendered again? If so, you could implement the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) such that the character is observed and your game an observer.

I think the trick will be to break the problem down into a few classes that have appropriate responsibilities--ideally a class should have one responsibility and each of its methods should do one thing.

Just some ideas to help you move forward. Experiment with it and see how it goes. Hope it helps!